# Python: Converting from `datetime.datetime` to `time.time`

Tags: python, time, calendar

In Python, how do I convert a `datetime.datetime` into the kind of `float` that I would get from the `time.time` function?

Comment: related: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's not hard to use the time tuple method and still retain the microseconds:

```
>>> t = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 5, 11, 26, 15, 37496)

>>> time.mktime(t.timetuple()) + t.microsecond / 1E6
1320517575.037496
```

Comment: Can you explain why this solution is better than `(dt - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()`? The manual addition of microseconds seems inelegant to me.

Comment: @RamRachum: your formula assumes that `dt` is UTC time. `mktime()` assumes that the input is local time. You should avoid using naive datetime objects that represent local time unless you want to display them immediately. Use UTC time or timezone-aware datetime objects instead.

Answer (score 34):

```
time.mktime(dt_obj.timetuple())
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: This drops the sub-second part of the time.

Comment: +1 because this answer is helpful anyway and the downvote isn't justified.

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old question, but in python 3.3+ there is now an easier way to do this using the [datetime.timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()
```

Comment: `timestamp = time.time()`

Comment: That would handle this specific case (find current timestamp), but using ``datetime.timestamp()`` is more powerful because it allows you to find the timestamp at an arbitrary datetime.

Comment: Provide a better example then. Because `.now().timestamp()` is strictly worse than `time.time()`. The former may produce a wrong result during DST transitions. A better example: `.now(utc).timestamp()` (at least, it produces the right result).

Answer (score 10):

Given a `datetime.datetime` object `dt`, you could use

```
(dt - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
```

Example:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now(); t = time.time()
>>> t
1320516581.727343
>>> (dt - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
1320516581.727296
```

Note that the `timedelta.total_seconds()` method was introduced in Python 2.7.

Comment: `((24*3600*td.days + td.seconds)*1000000 + td.microseconds)/1e6` on Python <2.7

Answer (score 7):

A combination of `datetime.timetuple()` and `time.mktime()`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> secondsSinceEpoch = time.mktime(now.timetuple())
```

Comment: This drops the sub-second part of the time.

Comment: +1 because this answer is helpful anyway and the downvote isn't justified.

Comment: I personally prefer one great answer over 4 okay ones, at least when it comes to software. But to each his own.

Comment: To strengthen Ram's comment: an answer that appears mostly right while hiding subtle bugs has negative value.