# Python's `fromtimestamp` does a discrete jump

Tags: python, datetime, calendar, epoch

I am using `datetime.fromtimestamp` to convert epoch time into local time. I found that `datetime.fromtimestamp` does a discrete jump of one hour at a certain point of time and I am completely baffled as to why it does that.

(I am also using `time.mktime` to convert a datetime object into epoch time, [as suggested by Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8022340/76701). I'm not sure whether this is relevant information for this question, so I'm saying this just in case.)

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time, datetime
>>> def datetime_to_epoch_time(datetime_):
...     return time.mktime(datetime_.timetuple()) + datetime_.microsecond / 1e6
...
```

Picking a specific epoch time:

```
>>> x = datetime_to_epoch_time(datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 30, 3, 0))
```

Converting it to a datetime using `fromtimestamp`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x)
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 30, 3, 0)
```

We get a time of 3am.

Now let's convert the time that's exactly one second before it:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x-1)
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 30, 1, 59, 59)
```

**We suddenly get 1:59am!**

What happened? I know that stuff like that happens around leap days, but since when is March 30th a leap day?

I should note that I've had this happen to me only on Linux and not on Windows. And I think that different Linux computers (in different timezones) have a different time point in which `fromtimestamp` does the jump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy. March 30th is presumably a daylight savings time switch in your timezone.

So on that day, time did indeed go from 1:59:59 to 3:00:00

Comment: I see. So `fromtimestamp` is aware of the time zone I live in and knows which hours to skip. But `datetime` objects aren't aware of this jump: If I subtract the `datetime` object for 3am from the one for 2am, I get a `timedelta` of one hour, where I should be getting zero.

Comment: How, then, do I make `datetime` objects aware of my timezone, and make them use the *exact* some timezone as `fromtimestamp`, so they will be completely synchronized?

Comment: @RamRachum Pass the `tzinfo` flag when constructing the timestamp. the `pytz` library may be of some help with that.

Comment: @Amber But how will I know that the `pytz` library is giving me the exact same timezone that `fromtimestamp` is using? If `fromtimestamp` is using a certain timezone that already exists on my computer without installing `pytz`, is it possible for me to use it?

Answer (score 9):

`fromtimestamp` uses the current user's "local environment", as defined by the POSIX C library (see `man (3) tzset`, and docs of the `time` module).

If you really want to get a `pytz` representation of the current user's environment's local-time, the [`datetime-tz`](http://code.google.com/p/python-datetime-tz/) package has a function for auto-detecting it.

However, common wisdom is to work always with UTC, and avoid all DST issues (use local timezone only for final display). Use `datetime.fromtimestamp(x, tz=pytz.UTC)`, or, if you do not have `pytz`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x)
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 30, 3, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x)
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 30, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x-1)
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 29, 23, 59, 59)
```

P.S. You can also set your process' locale to UTC (but this might not work on non-POSIX OS's):

```
>>> import os,time
>>> os.environ["TZ"] = "UTC"
>>> time.tzset()
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x)
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 30, 0, 0)
```